# Opengl Skybox Depth Buffer Hides the scene

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, skybox, depth-testing

Depth Buffer was working fine Until I added the Skybox, now it hides all my world(scene) and only renders the skybox when hiddenDepth=False...
The issue is clearly the skybox as I checked it by removing skybox...

Display Function below

```
static void display()
{
  if (hiddenDepth) 
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
  else {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

        glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(15500, 15500, 15500);
        glTranslatef(0,0.5, 0);
        drawskybox();
        glPopMatrix();
        glScalef(40, 40, 40);
        drawWorld();

}
```

Here is My Skybox

```
    glPushMatrix();
   glPushAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    // Render the quad

    glPopAttrib();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Hidden Depth Call (true,false on key press)

```
if (hiddenDepth)
  {
    // Now do z buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthRange(nearPlane,farPlane);
    glClearDepth(farPlane);
  }
```

InitGrapics

```
static void initGraphics (void)
{
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Main Function

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGB);

  glutInitWindowSize(550, 550);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 75);
  glutCreateWindow("Cube");

  initGraphics();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutReshapeFunc(resize);
  
  glutKeyboardFunc(asciiKey);
  glutSpecialFunc(specialKey);
  
  glutIdleFunc(idleRoutine);
  glutTimerFunc(timerMSecs,timer,0);
  
  glutMainLoop();
  /* Should never get here, but keeps compiler happy */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see any obvious issue in this code. The skybox is drawn first and the depth test is always disabled when the sybox is drawn.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) I am also figuring it what is the issue :(

Comment: What about drawing skybox at the end? any suggestion ?

Comment: I recommend to find the bug in your application. In general your approach is correct. If it doesn't work, you have a bug in your application. Anyway you can draw the skybox at the end The depth test has to be enabled, the depth function has to be `GL_LEQUAL` ([`glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthFunc.xhtml)) and you have to draw the skybox with a z coordinate of 1.0. The matrices have to be the identity matrices (`GL_MODELVIEW` and `GL_PROJECTION`).

Comment: I'll try that thanks

Comment: Fixed !!! Issue is I am using both Depth_Test and DepthMask in Skybox Function...it works only with DepthMask.

Comment: Any tutorial on Moon light in opengl? I am done with sun light in my Project...Just curious how moon light works...Like sun or it is different

Answer (score 0):

Fixed !!! Issue is I am using both Depth_Test and DepthMask in Skybox Function...it works only with DepthMask